# Range Find method showing String as Integer and hence showing Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find if comment in Sheet1.Cells(1,1) is already updated/available in Master-sheet (i.e. Sheet2) in range as shown below using Range Find.

```
Dim Find_Comment As Range
Set Find_Comment = Sheet2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Find(what:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1))
```

This is working for 99% cases but one comment I am attaching below is giving me *Type Mismatch error*.

Comment:

> Spoke to Mr.XYZ on 9900000099, said overall satisfied and rated 5/5
>   marks. Concern - Customer said steering cross at 60-70 speed on plain
>   road & W/A side bold nut was not available in showroom at the time of
>   work.  , Spoke to Mr.XYA on 9900000099, said overall satisfied with
>   the service and rated 5/5.

In Watch Window, LHS i.e. `Find_Comment` is shown as *Range type* whereas RHS i.e. `Sheet2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Find(what:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1))` is shown as *Integer type*.

The comment is having multiple spaces, inappropriate use of punctuation marks & even couple of line-breaks (including line-break at the end of comment)

May I know what should I do to resolve this *Type Mismatch error* ?

Comment: for starters, use `Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(1, 5)).Find(what:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value2)`, to be sure those `Cells` really belong to `Sheet2`, and don't relay on this latter being the active sheet

Comment: @HTH Thank you but this isn't working. I guess problem is not with code but with content of string I am trying to find which I have mentioned in Question above.

Comment: That was _"for starters"_. As for the rest, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main issue is in the length of searched string: `Find()` accepts up to 255 characters

so, if proper for your necessities, you may use

```
    Dim Find_Comment As Range
    With Sheet2
        Set Find_Comment = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 5)).Find(what:=Left$(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value, 255), LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart)
    End With
```

as you see:

- use `With .. End With` block to reference a specific object (`Sheet2` in this case) and inside it use dots (`.`) before its each child member (like `Range`, `Cells`, …) to be make sure they do belong to referenced object
- use `Left$()` function to truncate searched string to 255 characters
- you always want to explicitly declare `LookAt` and `LookIn` parameters of `Range.Find()` method since their default values are assumed as their last used values even from Excel UI interface

Comment: @Puntal, any feedback?

Comment: @ HTH amazing support actually. Used this code for around 2000 records I have. Code is running superbly. Thank you.